# Python Pandas Reformat stacked columns to long(?) format

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, melt

I have a csv file that looks like this:

[image: Current csv]

And I want it to look like this:

[image: Desired Format]

Basically, the country, month, year, and code would repeat, and the Valor export and Volumen export would be unique for the row.. The ending columns can be in any order.

I have tried doing a series of melt, pivot, transpose etc. with no luck. Can any please provide any guidance? Any hints would be greatly appreciated. I am just stumped how to deal with the original csv having the year/month/export value being "stacked"...

Here is the dictionary that can be used to recreate the original csv as a Pandas Data Frame:

`pd.DataFrame([{'Unnamed: 0': np.nan, 'Unnamed: 1': np.nan, '2017': 'Enero', 'Unnamed: 3': np.nan, 'Unnamed: 4': 'Febrero', 'Unnamed: 5': np.nan}, {'Unnamed: 0': np.nan, 'Unnamed: 1': np.nan, '2017': 'Valor export', 'Unnamed: 3': 'Volumen export', 'Unnamed: 4': 'Valor export', 'Unnamed: 5': 'Volumen export'}, {'Unnamed: 0': np.nan, 'Unnamed: 1': np.nan, '2017': np.nan, 'Unnamed: 3': np.nan, 'Unnamed: 4': np.nan, 'Unnamed: 5': np.nan}, {'Unnamed: 0': '080390110000 SA-2017', 'Unnamed: 1': 'USA', '2017': '29200.10725', 'Unnamed: 3': '67198.189', 'Unnamed: 4': '38631.16383', 'Unnamed: 5': '87962.196'}, {'Unnamed: 0': '090390110000 SA-2017', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Mexico', '2017': '9283.79255', 'Unnamed: 3': '21638.126', 'Unnamed: 4': '9785.40009', 'Unnamed: 5': '22863.867'}, {'Unnamed: 0': '010390110000 SA-2017 ', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Canada', '2017': '8017.55675', 'Unnamed: 3': '19352.178', 'Unnamed: 4': '11137.27057', 'Unnamed: 5': '27020.428'}, {'Unnamed: 0': '070390110000 SA-2017', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Brazil', '2017': '3786.44363', 'Unnamed: 3': '8704.871', 'Unnamed: 4': '4553.70795', 'Unnamed: 5': '10583.833'}, {'Unnamed: 0': '060390110000 SA-2017', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Italy', '2017': '4809.76636', 'Unnamed: 3': '12411.691', 'Unnamed: 4': '4304.02052', 'Unnamed: 5': '11198.063'}, {'Unnamed: 0': '000390110000 SA-2017  ', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Spain', '2017': '2290.65793', 'Unnamed: 3': '6227.269', 'Unnamed: 4': '3269.41957', 'Unnamed: 5': '9118.595'}, {'Unnamed: 0': '0990390110000 SA-2017  ', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Costa Rica', '2017': '1855.70035', 'Unnamed: 3': '4687.714', 'Unnamed: 4': '2668.57892', 'Unnamed: 5': '6425.365'}, {'Unnamed: 0': '0040390110000 SA-2017 ', 'Unnamed: 1': 'Honduras', '2017': '1823.358', 'Unnamed: 3': '4223.521', 'Unnamed: 4': '250.2036', 'Unnamed: 5': '603.392'}])`

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.strip()

idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [("2017",), ("Enero", "Febrero"), ("Valor Export", "Volumen Export")],
    names=("Year", "Month", "Export"),
)
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.iloc[3:, :2], names=("Code", "Country"))

df2 = (
    pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[3:, 2:].values, columns=idx1, index=idx2)
    .stack(level=(0, 1))
    .reset_index()
)
df2.columns.name = None
print(df2.sort_values(by=["Year", "Month"]).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Code | Country | Year | Month | Valor Export | Volumen Export |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 080390110000 SA-2017 | USA | 2017 | Enero | 29200.1 | 67198.2 |
| 090390110000 SA-2017 | Mexico | 2017 | Enero | 9283.79 | 21638.1 |
| 010390110000 SA-2017 | Canada | 2017 | Enero | 8017.56 | 19352.2 |
| 070390110000 SA-2017 | Brazil | 2017 | Enero | 3786.44 | 8704.87 |
| 060390110000 SA-2017 | Italy | 2017 | Enero | 4809.77 | 12411.7 |
| 000390110000 SA-2017 | Spain | 2017 | Enero | 2290.66 | 6227.27 |
| 0990390110000 SA-2017 | Costa Rica | 2017 | Enero | 1855.7 | 4687.71 |
| 0040390110000 SA-2017 | Honduras | 2017 | Enero | 1823.36 | 4223.52 |
| 080390110000 SA-2017 | USA | 2017 | Febrero | 38631.2 | 87962.2 |
| 090390110000 SA-2017 | Mexico | 2017 | Febrero | 9785.4 | 22863.9 |
| 010390110000 SA-2017 | Canada | 2017 | Febrero | 11137.3 | 27020.4 |
| 070390110000 SA-2017 | Brazil | 2017 | Febrero | 4553.71 | 10583.8 |
| 060390110000 SA-2017 | Italy | 2017 | Febrero | 4304.02 | 11198.1 |
| 000390110000 SA-2017 | Spain | 2017 | Febrero | 3269.42 | 9118.59 |
| 0990390110000 SA-2017 | Costa Rica | 2017 | Febrero | 2668.58 | 6425.36 |
| 0040390110000 SA-2017 | Honduras | 2017 | Febrero | 250.204 | 603.392 |